# Salesforce Redirect to Salesforce ID based on External ID

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am wanting to send someone into Salesforce using our External ID (that is stored in Salesforce) then have some process bounce them to the correct page in Salesforce.

So, for example, I have an External ID for Account and Opportunity.  Lets assume they are Account.AccountExtID__c and Opportunity.OpportunityExtID__c.

What I would like to be able to do is construct URLs using my External ID (i.e. https://thisismyorg.my.salesforce.com/OpportunityExtID__c) then have Salesforce lookup the OpportunityExtID__c on the relevant object (via SOQL or whatever), then redirect the user to the correct page (https://thisismyorg.my.salesforce.com/006xxxxxxxxxxx).

What would be the best way to go about this (if this is even possible)?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Internal users or Site/community/experience? Have you seen https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_site_urlRewriter.htm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a visualforce page to redirect to the opportunity using an external Id (any).
the url would be something like: https://thisismyorg.my.salesforce.com/apex/OppExt?extId=OpportunityExtID__c

create an apex controller similar to this one:

```
public class OpportunityRedirectController {

public Opportunity opp { get; set; }
public String extId { get; set; }

public OpportunityRedirectController() {
    extId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('extId');
    opp = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE External_Id__c = :extId limit 1];
}

public PageReference redirect() {
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + opp.Id);
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;
}
}
```

change the External_Id__c field to your external Id, if you have several change it to this:
public class OpportunityRedirectController {

```
public Opportunity opp { get; set; }
public String extId { get; set; }

public OpportunityRedirectController() {
    extId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('extId');
    opp = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE External_Id__c = :extId OR External_Id_2__c = :extId limit 1];
}

public PageReference redirect() {
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + opp.Id);
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;
}
}
```

Than create a page with these contents:

```
<apex:page controller="OpportunityRedirectController" action="{!redirect}">
</apex:page>
```

this should get you started, it will however fail when there is no opportunity found.

possible test class:

```
@isTest
private class OpportunityRedirectControllerTest {

    @isTest static void testRedirect() {
        // Create a test opportunity
        Opportunity testOpp = new Opportunity(Name='Test Opp', External_Id__c='1234');
        insert testOpp;

        // Instantiate the controller
        OpportunityRedirectController controller = new OpportunityRedirectController();

        // Set the external ID parameter
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('extId', '1234');

        // Test that the controller retrieves the correct opportunity and redirects to its page
        System.assertEquals(controller.opp.Id, testOpp.Id);
        System.assertEquals(controller.redirect().getUrl(), '/' + testOpp.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is fabulous, exactly what I was after, thank you.  Now to work out the test class!!

Comment: added a sample test class for you (and others that stumble upon this) ;)